# Ubuntu : Kerberos With LDAP

Tags: 12.04, ldap, openldap, kerberos

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I  am installing LDAP with Kerberos authentication. I followed the steps in the ubuntu documentation.

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/kerberos-ldap.html
```

After installation , when I am using `kadmin.local` command , it says invalid credentials. Here is the output.

```
# kadmin.local 

Authenticating as principal root/admin@CSEZ.ZOHOCORPIN.COM with password.
kadmin.local: Invalid credentials while initializing kadmin.local interface
```

My Configuration Files

**krb5.conf**

https://docs.zoho.com/writer/published.do?rid=cm31cdf3431525e96401bba98532403b252bb

**kdc.conf**

https://docs.zoho.com/writer/published.do?rid=cm31c3c78ac3564e6478ea82f9912cef72f8f

**ldap.conf**

https://docs.zoho.com/writer/published.do?rid=cm31c7470b21437134f50bedf0d3c1b9fbafb

**service.keyfile**

```
cn=admin,dc=csez,dc=zohocorpin,dc=com#{HEX}5153437668693132
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply but I based on what you shown above, I would expect your admin/olcRootDN to be in dc=ultrasound,dc=zmedia,dc=com, not in dc=csez,dc=zohocorpin,dc=com